# Java Serialization Performance regarding GWT

Tags: java, performance, gwt, serialization

I have a GWT application where the server part gets a lot of data sets from a mySQL database (10000+). Using this data the server initializes objects (and furthermore an ArrayList as parameter with a lot more objects from other mySQL tables). This objects will be serialized and send to the client.

My project works very well with only 1-5000 data sets. By serializing more then 10000+ objects  I feel like I'm getting some performance issues, it takes several seconds until the browser loads all data into a table. Using FireBug I can see that by using about 10000 objects the server is sending more then 300kB data to the client. Quite much considering that I would like my application to run smooth with at least 50000 data sets / objects.

Are they any hints which would increse the performance or reduce the overhead?

Like I said I'm using an ArrayList with custom classes/objects (actually I only need something where I can store a lot of classes dynamically while I'm not accessing any objects randomly or something like that).

I feel like GWT serializes custom classes/objects quite slow. Is it so?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: which widget are you using for the table?

Comment: Profile your code to find out the bottleneck. Is it the server side serialization ? Is it the serialization on the client side ? Is it the rendering of objects. 

Apart from that displaying huge tables is from a UX point of view an anti-pattern. Either use infinite scrolling or pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a celltable, you can use PAGING (see http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#paging), so only a part of the data will be loaded.

> Paging is the operation of loading and bringing into view a range of data that is not currently loaded. Paging improves initial load time of large data sets by loading only the data that is needed by the current view.